# How to reactively define first column with dplyr in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

Let's say I want to have a user-uploaded dataset similar to the CO2 one provided in R in my Shiny app.  I'm looking for people to load any dataset of this type and then generate a new value from existing ones using dplyr's `mutate`.  I've coded reactive values that check to see if "conc" and "uptake" are present in the data, and if so to use them to generate the new value.

I then want a new table rendered that shows the first column (that identifies the sample) and this new value.  However, since the datasets will change depending on user input, I can't specify the column (for the CO2 dataset, it would be "Plants").

Here's my toy example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv',
                       'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                       '.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'),',')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("inputfile"),
    tableOutput("do")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  upData <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file1)) return(CO2)
    inFile <- input$file1
    dat <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    return(dat)
  })

output$inputfile <- renderTable({
    head(upData())
  })

  concvar <- reactive({
    if("conc" %in% colnames(upData())==TRUE) {upData()$conc} 
    else{0} 
  })

  uptakevar <- reactive({
    if("uptake" %in% colnames(upData())==TRUE) {upData()$uptake} 
    else{0} 
  })

  newvalue <- reactive({
    upData() %>% 
      mutate(newvalue=concvar()/uptakevar()) %>% 
      select(newvalue)
  })

  output$do <- ({
    renderTable(head(newvalue()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This does almost everything I want, but I can't figure out how to get this new column of values to also have a column that identifies the respective sample.

I've tried defining `upData()[,1]` and using `select_` in the "newvalue" dplyr chain but I keep getting errors.  How can I reactively define the first column of various hypothetical datasets in a `select` call so my new values are contextualized with sample names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `concvar` and `uptakevar` functions are returning the full vector of the values, but you are trying to treat them as column names. Either, use the vectors directly like this:

```
newvalue <- reactive({
  data.frame(
    newvalue = concvar() / uptakevar()
  )
})
```

Or, return the column names, then use `mutate_` to construct the column of interest, like this. Note that I used `select_` as well to allow you to select the first column in addition to the `newvalue`. It would probably be even better to define this as a character as well (like your conc and uptake variables) to allow the user to pick a reasonable ID column to include (instead of assuming the first column is an ID).

```
concvar <- reactive({
  if("conc" %in% colnames(upData())==TRUE) {"conc"} 
  else{0} 
})

uptakevar <- reactive({
  if("uptake" %in% colnames(upData())==TRUE) {"uptake"} 
  else{0} 
})

newvalue <- reactive({
  upData() %>%
    mutate_(newvalue = paste(concvar(), "/", uptakevar())) %>% 
    select_(names(upData())[1], "newvalue")
})
```

I would recommend the latter, as I assume you are planning on using a select box of some sort to let the user pick the column names to use (which will return a character vector with the column name).

Comment: Hi Mark - this is very useful info, but I'm afraid I'm still missing how to go about constructing the sample (identifier) column I want.  This may just be a fundamental error in my understanding of data structure.  It seems like I should be able to write a line similar to 


`newvalue <- reactive({
  upData() %>%
    mutate_(newvalue = paste(concvar(), "/", uptakevar())) %>% 
    select(upData()[,1], newvalue)
}) ` 


and have that return the two columns I want (one identifying the plants in this case, and one identifying this new value).

Comment: `upData()[,1]`, like your original functions, is the vector of all values in the first column. See edit for a way to use `select_` to grab the first column with it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thanks!  I guess it's time to go back and read up on basic data structure....

Comment: Glad it helped -- the thing to keep in mind is just what is being returned from those reactives. When I hit errors like that, I tend to use `renderText` and `verbatimTextOutput` to see what the values actually contain. Here, I added `verbatimTextOutput("test")` to `ui` and `output$test <- renderText({ c(concvar(), uptakevar()) })` to `server` to see what was coming out of those.

Comment: That's an excellent debugging tip I will definitely be adding to my arsenal. Thanks again!